# Column Name is different after DB Migration using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration

I have this code I used for db migration using Sequelize

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('tasks', { 
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      uuid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      task: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      status: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
        allowNull: false
      },
      completedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    await queryInterface.dropTable('tasks');
  }
};
```

After running `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` it successfully created a table in PhpMyAdmin. The problem is, I specified in my migration file the column names `createdAt` and `completedAt` but in my PhpMyAdmin, the column names have a different format namely: `created_at` and `completed_at`.

I did `created_at` and `completed_at` on my previous migration so what I did was to undo it, so it deleted the table in my DB. So I created another migration using the code above but I still have the same column names, `created_at` and `completed_at` when I should be getting `createdAt` and `completedAt` instead.

Comment: The migration script working fine for me. Could you try to check your model? Perhaps you did not update your model and sync with your DB when you start your application.

Comment: @TekLoon Mine worked. I reverted my migration and replaced my 'completed_at' to 'updatedAt'. Also added createdAt and deletedAt.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my `completed_at` column and used `created_At` , `updatedAt` , `deletedAt`